# Replace text value with Font Awesome icon

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table and want to change all cells within a column that has a value greater than '1' to a Font Aweseome icon. The below 'works', but it is printing the code instead of the icon itself.

```
$('.data-mvp').each(function(i, n) {
if($(n).text() > 0) $(n).text('<i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true">
</i>');
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the .html() instead of the .text()

Also you need to both get the value from each element and convert it to a number before comparing it to a numeric value - then if its greater than 0 - set the HTML of the element.

Also you say in the text that if the value is greater than "1" then you want to alternate HTML but in the code you have the test being if its greater than "0"... so i made it change if the value is greater or equal to "1" - you may need to change that.....

```
$('.data-mvp').each(function() {
  var testVal = parseInt($(this).text());
  if(testVal >= 1) {
     $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  }
});
```